# What command can I use to stop receiving a defuse kit every round in casual?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

My friends and I wanted to play a 5v5 premade and make it look like a competitive match. I got all the commands except for the one that disables a defuse kit being bought automatically after each round.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the console, type:

```
mp_defuser_allocation "0"
```

This will not give a defuser kit to anyone, allowing you to buy one for its full price ($400).